# Can't import rospy in Debian 11 bullseye. Although pakage is installed it shows no module named rospy

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, ros, rospy, bullseye

I installed rospy package from Pip3 and it worked fine on my Windows, Similarly i tried it with bullseye Debian 11 (on my raspberry pi3b+), it downloaded successfully but it wont import rospy and shows the error no module named rospy.

My code is ready. How to install rospy in the bullseye, I've searched every bit of internet yet cant find a solution for this. I want ros to implement the movement of servo motors for my Robotic Hand.

I tried to install Rospy for Debian 11 but everywhere it shows that bullseye don't support ROS. in addition they start doing stuff for Ros Desktop. I don't need Ros Desktop i need just to import Rospy in my script. It is installed already in my Desbian 11 but when i try to remove it, it says "Nothing found to delete"

Comment: There was no image attached

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to install and use rospy on Debian 11 (Bullseye) which is not officially supported by ROS. ROS only officially supports Ubuntu and some other operating systems, but not Debian 11.

However, there are some community-supported ways to install ROS on Debian 11. One of them is to use the ROS Docker images, which can be used to run ROS on any operating system that supports Docker. You can find more information on using ROS Docker images on the official ROS Wiki page.

Alternatively, you can try to manually install and configure ROS on Debian 11 by following the instructions provided on the ROS Wiki page for Debian. This may require some additional effort and troubleshooting to get it working on Debian 11.

Once you have successfully installed ROS on Debian 11, you should be able to install rospy using pip3 or apt-get, depending on how you installed ROS. If you installed ROS using apt-get, you should be able to install rospy using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-rospy
```

If you installed ROS using Docker, you can use pip3 to install rospy:

```
sudo pip3 install rospy
```

Once rospy is installed, you should be able to import it in your Python script and use it to control your robotic hand.